# How To fix "PHP Fatal error: Class 'ffmpeg_movie' not found" Error in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I have installed FFMPEG in my server for video conversions into different sizes of videos within my WordPress site running on *PHP 5.6/Linux*. Previously all things were working fine but today suddenly I got one error like:

> "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ffmpeg_movie' not found".
>
> PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ffmpeg.so' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/ffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I have searched solution for this error, so I got one solution like include autoload.php file. Which I have already included.

So can anyone help me to solve out this problem?

Comment: Why is *wordpress* tagged? You did not mention in the question.

Comment: Because i have installed and set-up all this things in my wordpress website.

Comment: Wich system is PHP running on? Add the output of `php -m` to your question please.

Comment: It's important to mention Wordpress since there might be a conflict in order to an update, possibly an incompatible plugin to the version. Have there been any updates prior to this error?

Comment: PHP 5.6 is running on my system.

Comment: Linux or Windows?

Comment: Ohh it's linux  is running on

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186953/discussion-between-quasimodos-clone-and-ajay-katariya).